# Rotate point A towards point B around point C on a plane

Tags: math, vector, rotation

So I am using a DSL that doesn't have stuff like quaternions or matrices, or most any libraries that are common to the answers of questions like this. With all that being said, I'll draw a picture to hopefully more clearly illustrate what I'm trying to get at here.

[image]

- A is our first point.
- B is our second point.
- C is the point we want to rotate around.
- D is a unit vector defining the plane on which we are rotating. (It's the normal of the plane)

I want to get X after passing in a value from 0 - 1. 0 == A and 1 == B. C will always be equidistant between A and B, and as C gets closer to A and B, the arc will become more pronounced, until it becomes a half circle, and the farther away it gets, the flatter the curve will be.

Now, if there's other information I need for this to work, I can write it out, as long as it doesn't involve using libraries or anything like that. Assume the language I'm in basically lua, as in no batteries, and anything you suggest I will need to create myself. So far, I have code for getting A, B, C, and D, but it's this last step I'm stuck on. I don't know how to rotate around C using D, and I don't know how to figure out how much I need to rotate to get from A to B, since C can be any distance away from A/B.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! It took me like 8 hours to find what I was looking for, so I'll post it here for posterity. This is sort of pseduo code-y, since posting my actual code from the language I'm using wouldn't really be helpful.

````lua
function slerpish(a, b, center, t)
    c = a - center
    d = b - center
    omega = acos(dot(c, d) / pow(distance(a, center), 2))
    s = sin(omega)
    return (c * sin((1 - t) * omega) / s) + (d * sin(t * omega) / s)```
````